# Convergence of martingale (reference)

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a sequence of processes $\{X^N(t)\}_{t\in [0,T]}$, $N\in\mathbb N$ such that
$X^N(t)=x+M^N(t)$,
where $M^N(t)$ is a martingale with expectation $0$ and with quadratic variation $\langle M^N \rangle (t)$  such that
$\langle M^N \rangle(t)-\int_0^tX^N(s)(1-X^N(s))ds\xrightarrow[N\to+\infty]{}0$ in probability.

I know that the process $X^N(t)$ converges (I proved its tightness), I would like to conclude that $X^N(t)\to X(t)$ where $X(t)$ is the solution of the following system of SDE
$$dX(t)=\sqrt{X(t)(1-X(t)}dB(t)$$
$$X(0)=x$$
with $B(t)$ the classic Brownian motion.

Could someone suggest me a book in which I can find a theorem that could help me with the convergence of martingales?